# Prevent Export to CAD to add exported data to the map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, cad

Is there a way to prevent ArcMap from automatically adding Export to CAD results to the current map?

**Export Data** gives you the choice when the operation is completed but **Export to CAD** does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to "Geoprocessing" menu then "Geoprocessing options". Untick "Add result of geoprocessing operations to the display". It should do the trick (worked for me).

[image: Geoprocessing options]